# How to ensure, ViewModel property is bound already on view before changing it value again?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

There is following case:
`ViewModel` has an object which changes very fast. (via different threads)

`View` gets informed via `NotifyPropertyChanged` interface but it seems it works to slow and before View bind new value and draw it then it changes more times therefore It misses some values.

I also tried to bind `View` to queue then `ViewModel` could `Enqueue` it and `View` could draw via dequeueing.

Unfortunately another problem occurred: after `RaisePropertyChanged(() => queue);` `View` is not informed that it was changed.

In such case the implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface did not worked.

Do you have any idea?

Example code of the `ViewModel`:

```
public class ExamplaryViewModel
{
    public ExamplaryViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Message>>(this, m => ProcessNotificationMessage(m.Content));
    }    

    public void ProcessNotificationMessage(Message message)
    {   
        MessageOftenBeingChanged = message;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageOftenBeingChanged );
    }
}
```

`View` binds to `MessageOftenBeingChanged`.

Another option would be to prepare snapshot as was suggested in comments:

```
public void ProcessNotificationMessage(Message message)
{
    Messages.Enqueue(message);
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Messages);
}
```

`View`:

```
<controls:RichTextBoxMonitor Messages="{Binding Messages}
```

`Control`:

```
public class BindableRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Messages",
     typeof(ConcurrentQueue<Message>), typeof(BindableRichTextBox ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnQueueChangedChanged));


    public ConcurrentQueue<Message> CyclicMessages
    {
        get { return (ConcurrentQueue<Message>)GetValue(MessagesProperty ); }

        set { SetValue(MessagesProperty , value); }
```

but then, unfortunately the `RaisePropertyChanged()` method does not trigger that changes happened.

I planned in control in event `OnQueueChangedChanged` try dequeueing and just draw items as new Inlines for Paragraph.

Comment: What about starting the threads after the view creation is done?

Comment: Can you show a sample code of your viewmodel?

Comment: I think I did something similar once where I had a timer which triggered the Change event at set interval, then used a while loop to drain the queue so it didn't fall behind

Comment: Sounds like a bit wrong design. What if you never display the view? Such things as data for the view has to be processed by Model and prepared (for displaying) by ViewModel. What ViewModel typically should do is to provide snapshot (of data), which is sufficient for the View to display. You have to provide more details if you want to get help with how it can be optimized (if binding is too slow for you).

Comment: I added examplary code which shows how it is prepared. You are right that ViewModel should provide some sort of shanpshot therefore I used to enqueue newly added data in some container e.g. ConcurrentQueue but then View was very inefficient since everytime it was notified about property changed it has to redraw itself with full whole buffer

Comment: 'RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageOftenBeingChanged );' is redundant if your property is subscribed to NotifyPropertyChanged. It should update all by itself. It looks like you're using MVVM Light. Have you considered setting the MessageOftenBeingChanged property directly, rather than going through the Messenger system? In your sending ViewModel, something like _myViewModelLocator.ExamplaryViewModel.MessageOftenBeingChanged = myValue; .

Comment: @lukaszk, could you please post the implementation of the `MessageOftenBeingChanged` property?

Comment: MessageOftenBeingChanged is just a Message, which contains such field as Info ForegroundColor,

Comment: @lukaszk, okay, could you please post the implementation of the property? Also, to be able to reproduce the problem, could you please post the implementation of the `Message` class and the implementation of background  worker threads that update the instances of the `Message` class?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Look at this simplified version.

- `RunProducer` is only for tests, in your case `ProcessNotificationMessage` will work in a similar way.
- `RunConsumer` is a method which constantly checks for new messages and sets `Message` with some delay, otherwise a user wouldn't be able to read it.
- It's just a quick proof of concept, but you could implement it better, for example by providing a methods `ShowNextMessage` and `IsMessageAvailable`, then the view could decide when is ready to display a new message and request for it. It would be a better design. Even a user could hide some messages faster then, you'd need only to bind `ShowNextMessage` to `Click` event.
- [Full source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105509493/udostepnione/Messages.zip)

  ```
  public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public ConcurrentQueue<string> Queue { get; set; }

      #region Message

      private string _message;

      public string Message
      {
          get
          {
              return _message;
          }
          set
          {
              if (_message != value)
              {
                  _message = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged();
              }
          }
      }
      #endregion

      public MyViewModel()
      {
          Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
          RunProducer();
          RunConsumer();
      }

      public void RunProducer()
      {
          Task.Run(() =>
          {
              int i = 0;
              while (true)
              {
                  if (Queue.Count < 10)
                      Queue.Enqueue("TestTest " + (i++).ToString());
                  else
                      Task.Delay(500).Wait();
              }
          });
      }

      public void RunConsumer()
      {
          Task.Run(() =>
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  if (Queue.Count > 0)
                  {
                      string msg = "";
                      if (Queue.TryDequeue(out msg))
                          Message = msg;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Task.Delay(500).Wait();
                  }

                  Task.Delay(100).Wait();
              }
          });
      }

      #region INotifyPropertyChanged

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
          {
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }

      #endregion
  }
  ```

In case of empty queue you could use `ManualResetMonitor` to avoid unnecessary iterations.

**Remarks to your code:**
If a collection can be changed then for binding purpose you should use only `ObservableCollection<T>` (or something that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`), because it tracks changes and doesn't reload everything.

However in your code a whole binding should be refreshed (as you notified that whole collection has been changed), but I think this mechanism is smarter and checks if references are equal, if so then no refresh occurs. Probably a hax to set it to `null` and back would refresh it :-).

Comment: @lukaszk does it answer your question?

Comment: your idea seems interesting but does not fully satisfy me. Maybe me question was not precise enough. Anyway many things happens since I created my question. My final solution I chose looks totally different. I decided to not use binding dirrectly to RichTextBox. I collects messages destined to be shown in queue buffer. Then I have something similar to your infinite Consumer which is based on DispatcherTimer and on each tick it collects some messages via dequeuing the queue. Then It raises event RaiseMonitorItemsAdd then in code begind view handles it and adds to RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Through many investigations I decided that binding to RichText box via any decorator, custom control with additional DependencyProperty and Converter is not efficient.

My conclusion shows that it is worthless to build custom richTextbox - and ensure somehow that new value is shown before it is changed.

I resign direct Binding.

I gather any new messages in buffer - queue.

I decided to use something similar to Consumer (as Wojciech Kulik suggested)

I based my consumer on TimeDispatcher which in its interval on Tick checks 
if any new messages exists in queue. If true then it dequeues and collects it and finally RaiseMonitorItemsAdd.

View handles above event that way:

```
  if (dataContext is IMonitorable)
        {
            Context = dataContext as IMonitorable;

            Context.MonitorViewModel.RaiseMonitorItemAdd += MonitorViewModelOnRaiseMonitorItemAdd;
            Context.MonitorViewModel.RaiseMonitorCleared += MonitorViewModel_RaiseMonitorCleared;
        }



    private void MonitorViewModelOnRaiseMonitorItemAdd(object sender, MonitorEventArgs monitorEventArgs)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            _paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(MonitorItemConverter.ConvertToInlines(monitorEventArgs.MonitorItem));
            _richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
        }));
    }
```

MoreOver in case RichTextBox gains to many items I dump whole log to file.