# Modifying a list from another thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application with a MainWindow that will be handling the output of messages. I've set up a list of messages in the Window like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ConcurrentBag<ViewMessage> MessageList
    {
        get { return (ConcurrentBag<ViewMessage>)GetValue(MessageListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MessageList", typeof(ConcurrentBag<ViewMessage>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string header, string message)
    {
        ViewMessage message = new ViewMessage("Sucess", "Example Message");
        MessageList.Add(message);
    }
}
```

The style of the messages is set to fade out after some time (3 seconds), and I want to remove the item from the collection after that time. I don't know if it's possible to do it in XAML only, if it is, how do I do it?

I tried doing it programatically like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MessageCheckTick);
    timer.Start();

    //Tried a Thread.Start() as well
}

private void MessageCheckTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = MessageList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        ViewMessage message = null;
        if (MessageList.TryPeek(out message))
        {
            if (message.DateMessage >= DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(3000))
            { MessageList.TryTake(out message); }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get errors of `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`.
I tried the solutions of similar questions in SO, like adding the ConcurrentBag or using the `Dispatcher`, but they didn't work.
In the case of the `Dispatcher` I can't call the `Thread.Sleep` since it's the main thread of the program.

How can I make this work?

Comment: editing a list from multiple threads can be dangerous, better bet is to create a method in the class where the list is located that handles removing items (with a object lock preferably)  then use a dispatcher checker and invoke if needed if called from an external thread,

Comment: Should use `ConcurrentQueue`.  `ConcurrentBag` is ideal for scenarios where the same thread is both a producer and consumer.

Comment: @Daniichi check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674539/how-to-ensure-viewmodel-property-is-bound-already-on-view-before-changing-it-va/30144697#30144697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DispatcherTimer` is a great idea. I would write the handler akin to this:

```
// remove outdated
var dtThreshold = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-3);
foreach (var el in _localObservable.Where(i => i.DateMessage < dtThreshold).ToList())
    _localObservable.Remove(el);

// add new
ViewMessage message = null;
while (MessageList.TryTake(out message))    
    _localObservable.Add(message);
```

The observable collection *must* be manipulated only from the UI thread – you therefore need to keep the ConcurrentBag (to add elements from the non-UI thread).

Few things to note:

- .ToList() in the remove section: this ensures that all to-be-removed candidates are determined before the first of them is actually removed (in this case, enumeration of the _localObservable ends before it's modified)
- No need to do `TryPeek` in advance - `TryTake` will take an element and remove it from the bag, giving you the element.

If you don't use ConcurrentBag then each `Add` operation must be posted to UI thread. A big number of `Add` events may pollute the UI thread, making everything slow & inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add this for completeness, there is [`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845.aspx) which does more or less what you ask - dispatch modifications to the collection on the correct thread.
If you want to use it go ahead, I've used it successfully many times (and before 4.5 did it manually); just take the time to understand everything that's going on, it definitely helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DispatcherTimer, which will elapse on the correct thread

You don't need to use ConcurrentBag. Looks like it should be an ObservableCollection

Comment: +1 on the O Collection for what looks like a notification pool of some sort. The registerable events for when messages are added will come in handy for when you want your UI thread to display them.